# Erro no upload de imagem PHP

Tags: file-upload

Blz Galera

Estou fazendo um teste de upload de imagem e está aparecendo o erro:

Notice: Undefined index: foto in C:\xampp\htdocs\cadastro.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: foto in C:\xampp\htdocs\cadastro.php on line 3

O que está errado? Desde já obrigado

Obs. O script no index.php é porque tenho mais de um botão no form.

index.php

```
<form id="cadastro" name="cadastro" method="post">
<input type="file" name="foto" />
<input type="button" value="Cadastrar" onClick="ExecutaAcao('cadastro');">
</form>

<script>
function ExecutaAcao(valor){
document.cadastro.action = valor + '.php';
document.cadastro.submit();
}
</script>
```

cadastro.php

```
<?php 
$imagem = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
$location = "imagens/$imagem";
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location);
?>
```

Comment: Coloque um id no seu input, talvez seja isso -> <input type="file" id="foto" name="foto" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione o `enctype` no seu form:

```
<form id="cadastro" name="cadastro" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Leia mais [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) e [aqui](https://html.com/attributes/form-enctype).

Comment: Deu certo. Muito obrigado Junior